# Java - connecting to a database on another pc

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

i have PC A that has a running wamp server with mysql database.

and PC B that wants to connect to that database, i am using Spring jpa, JDBC, trying to obtain direct access.

what i have done so far ?

the PC A connects to the database just fine as it is local.

PC B had no permissions to connect, "access denied" exception was thrown so i did the following :

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myDB To 'root'@'myip' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';

however, second try , another exception was thrown that says, user ''@'myip' has no privileges !

anyways just to make sure, i gave and empty user all privileges on that ip.

but still exception "select command denied" is thrown ,,(pretty sure it cant see the database)

these are my database.properties :

```
javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://myIp:3306/myDB?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
javax.persistence.jdbc.user=root
javax.persistence.jdbc.password=root
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

spring config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("chechecn.elections.organizer.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("chechecn.elections.organizer");

        factory.setJpaProperties(additionalJpaProperties());

        // factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    private Properties additionalJpaProperties() {
        Properties properties =     PropertiesReader.instance.getPropValues(PropertiesConstants.DATABASE_PROPERTIES);

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public ServiceConnector serviceConnector() {
        return new ServiceConnector();
    }
}
```

Comment: mysql set up to support networking ?

Comment: i really dont know ,, can you help please ? hint ?

Comment: @PauChorro not using that bean anyway

Comment: @NeilStockton solved ,, all i had to do was to enable root access for that ip

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you have root access for the other machine at that address?